# Distribution of Colour On Screen In YDSE Experiment

Tags: double-slit-experiment

In YDSE Experiement using white light my textbook says that the first colour to appear in immediate proxy of the central maximum(white spot) is the violet colour. The reason given for it is that the wavelength of violet colour is the smallest.[image: Image shows the formula for determining the position of maxima and minima]
**MY DOUBT IS:**
I can understand that the first maximum occurs of that colour which has the smallest wavelength but that also implies that it will be the first colour to have a minimum. Therefore according to me the first colour to be observed must be red. Am I right?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you are absolutely right ,
think of it this way- the rate of variation of violet light is max and rate of variation of red light is slowest when we move away from the white spot on screen so first colour to appear is red . We can also think of it as - the first minima occurs of violet colour hence on moving a little upwards the intensity due to violet will become zero hence leaving intensity due to red light there and therefore red colour should be observed on moving a little upwards from white spot first.